# Is it possible to automatically set numbers=none for single-line lstlisting environments?

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I apologise if the answer to my question can be found in the listings documentation and I missed it.

Essentially I would like line numbers to be set only if the number of lines is greater than one.

Comment: I'm assuming this will have to be performed in a two-pass fashion (first pass to store the total number of lines for each listing, and a second pass to add `numbers=none` to the single-line ones).